# Why is my custom css snippet not working?

Tags: css, code-snippets, emmet

I created a custom css snippet for nth-of-type keyword in css. But it doesn't seem to work. All other snippets work perfectly.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
nth-of-type(${1})
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>noty</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.css</scope>
</snippet>
```

But when I enter the tab trigger and press tab it just puts a colon ahead. Also I have installed Emmet and I think it might be conflicting with something here.
Also I've saved the snippet in the correct directory.

[image: Snippet fails]

Comment: noty is content... not an html element

Comment: But we can set it to anything we want right? For eg: In Js I set 'ael' tab trigger for "document.addEventListener" and it worked fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Philipp Sander says 'noty' is not an element. it's a content of the `<tabTrigger>`. CSS won't work for content.

You can use tag/an element name or you can use class/id property in an element, and use that class/id value to select that element.

**Id** property :
`<tabTrigger id="noty_element">noty</tabTrigger>`

styles for Id:

```
#noty_element {
     //your styles
}
```

**class** property :
`<tabTrigger class="noty_element">noty</tabTrigger>`

styles for Id:

```
.noty_element {
     //your styles
}
```

Comment: Ohh I get it. But how do I make it work for CSS then?